# Azure B2C Create User via AD Graph - Can't Login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using the Azure AD Graph to programatically crate a User.

My goal is to generate a temp password, then when the try to login with the temp password it immediately forces them to reset their password before proceeding.

I am able to successfully create the user. When I retrieve all users via the Graph, I see my user there. However when I attempt to login with the email/temp password, B2C says invalid email/pass.

What am I missing here?

My JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "yo@yo.com"
    }
  ],
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "Agent47",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "PassIsTemp1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": true
  },
  "country": "USA"
}
```

Comment: Hi @aherrick, I am having the same issue. Even i have created the user with "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false, as i just wanted to authenticate the user but i am getting the response "We couldn't find an account with that username.". Did you get resolution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following options with the built-in policies.

If you are wanting for the temporary password to be changed on the first sign-in, then you must [create a sign-in only policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-in-policy).

The sign-in only policy handles the **forceChangePasswordNextLogin** setting by prompting the authenticated user to enter their current and new passwords.

**Note:** The page UI customization feature that is described by [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) is not available to the sign-in only policy.

If the page UI customization feature is important, then you must:

1. [Create a sign-up or sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy).
2. When [creating a local account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#create-consumer-user-accounts), set the **forceChangePasswordNextLogin** to `false`.
3. Instruct the new user to "change" their temporary password through the "Forgot your password?" link [using a password reset policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-password-reset-policy).

You can otherwise consider [a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) from [the starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) that includes [a password change step](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/password-change).

Comment: But will that force them to change? Or at that point will it be optional? I don’t want them to have the option obviously.

Comment: Hi @aherrick I've updated the above answer with a few options.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So you’re saying I can’t do a sign up sign in policy and use force password change flag?

Comment: Correct, if the **forceChangePasswordNextLogin** property is set to `true`, then the sign-up and sign-in policy displays an invalid password error message.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I’m trying to understand how that makes sense. If the account is created already with an email address and a temp password, why would sign in to that account not work?

Comment: The sign-up or sign-in policy validates a user credential by sending a `grant_type=password` request to the Azure AD B2C directory. If the **forceChangePasswordNextLogin** property is set to `true`, then this request returns an "user_password_expired" error. The policy handles this error by displaying the "Invalid email address/user or password" error.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Would there be a simple way to have the policy simply redirect them to password reset?

Comment: Hi @aherrick, no, your B2C application initiates it. I suggest you [create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#create-a-custom-attribute) (e.g. "ForceResetPasswordNextLogin"), set this to `true` when you create the local account, and then issue this as an application claim from the sign-up or sign-in policy to your B2C application. After sign-in, if it is set to `true`, then your B2C application initiates the password reset policy. After password reset, then your B2C application sets it to `false`.

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks that’s something I can run with